# CPU Upgrade, is +10 TDP relevant?

Tags: laptop, cpu

I found that my motherboard socket supports other CPUs, so I want to upgrade my CPU, the question is: will I have any overheating problems by using a CPU which has a TDP of 35W, while mine has a TDP of 25W?

P.S.: It's a laptop, older CPU: Athlon II P320; newer one: Phenom II N660

Comment: You need to be more specific if you expect us to answer this question.

Comment: It most likely won’t fry the system outright, but in extreme cases the new CPU might be slower because it’s constantly throttling.

Comment: @DanielB What do you mean for throttling?

Comment: @boxHiccup - In this case Daniel's comment isn't applicable to your system.

Comment: @Ramhound It shouldn't be the opposite for dynamic frequency scaling?

Comment: @boxHiccup - I updated my comment.  The CPUs in question wouldn't throttle in either direction ( faster or slower) due to their age.  It is worth pointing out, I feel the higher TDP is a higher concern, then Daniel indicates.  I personally don't think the upgrade will work.  It likely won't harm anything, it simply won't work, since the motherboard won't supply the CPU enough power.

Comment: @boxHiccup When the CPU gets too hot, its performance is restricted until the temperature is within acceptable bounds again. This is referred to as thermal throttling.

Comment: Thank you both for the info. So is it worth? Could the computer shutdown for overheating? (My current CPU runs at 50° on idle and 59° while browsing)

Comment: @Ramhound Both CPUs have PowerNow!. They aren’t *that* old. Thermal throttling is unrelated to Turbo Core and has been around for much longer. It’s an essential safety feature. Check out [this entertaining video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y39D4529FM4).

Comment: @DanielB - I blame the website that I looked at.  It didn't meant a boost speed, of course AMD's own specification, sucks when you compare it to Intel's website.  That is an entirely different story.

Comment: @boxHiccup - Most CPUs will turn off if their temperatures are to high.  I couldn't say if that would happen your potential upgrade.

Comment: My computer already did that before when I reached 95/100° C (don't remember) with this CPU, then on restart I found a message: "Thermal shutdown occurred"